want to change center location of google map in flutter?
I've got an app design with a menu at the bottom and some extra info displayed in another box. Right next to that, there's a Google Map.
But the marker in the map, which loads up in the middle, doesn't look right.
I want to move the center of the map up by 25% from where it is now. Take a look at the picture I've attached and let me know how I can do this.


Can u write code of the widget ( in the middle of map )

maybe u can wrap column this widget and u can add Container with only height ( screen context.height * 0.08 ) to under of ur widget
like this
Column children: [
ur widget in the middle of map,
Container with ( context.size.height * 0.08 height )
]
